# Refreshing page causes component to not render again

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

i have a problem with Vue router. And more specifically, with refreshing the page after loading the path. When I open the country details page via router-link everything is fine but when I refresh the page it either shows nothing or throws an error. Thank you for any help.

main.js:

```
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from './views/Home.vue'
import AboutCountry from './views/AboutCountry.vue'
import NotFound from './components/NotFound.vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import './index.css'

const routes = [
  { path: '/countries', name: 'Home', component: Home, alias: '/' },
  { path: '/countries/:id', name: 'AboutCountry', component: AboutCountry },
  { path: '/:NotFound(.*)', component: NotFound }
]
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
  scrollBehavior() {
    return { top: 0 }
  }
})

const pinia = createPinia()
const app = createApp(App)
app.use(pinia)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

App.vue:

```
<template>
  <TheHeader />
  <router-view ></router-view>
</template>

<script>
import TheHeader from './components/TheHeader.vue'
import { useCountriesStore } from './stores/useCountriesStore'
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'

export default {
    data() {
        return {
            useCountriesStore: useCountriesStore()
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        this.useCountriesStore.fetchCountries();
        console.log("App mounted!");
    },
    components: { TheHeader }
}
</script>
```

AboutCountry.vue:

```
<template>
  <main class="px-8 pb-12 sm:px-16">
    <CountryDetails :country="country" />
  </main>
</template>

<script>
import CountryDetails from '../components/details/CountryDetails.vue'
import { useCountriesStore } from '../stores/useCountriesStore'

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      useCountriesStore: useCountriesStore()
    }
  },
  components: {
    CountryDetails
  },
  computed: {
    country() {
      return (this.country = this.useCountriesStore.countries.find(
        (country) => country.cca3 === this.$route.params.id
      ))
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

useCountriesStore.js:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useCountriesStore = defineStore('country', {
  state: () => {
    return {
      countries: [],
      filteredCountries: [],
      fetching: true
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getFilteredCountries(state) {
      return state.filteredCountries
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchCountries() {
      fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
        .then((res) => {
          if (res.ok) {
            return res.json()
          } else {
            return Promise.reject(`Http error: ${res.status}`)
          }
        })
        .then((res) => {
          this.countries = res
          this.filteredCountries = res
          this.fetching = false
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error)
        })
    },
    filterCountriesByRegion(region) {
      this.filteredCountries = this.countries.filter((country) => country.region.includes(region))
    },
    filterCountriesBySearch(input) {
      this.filteredCountries = this.countries.filter((country) =>
        country.name.official.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
      )
    }
  }
})
```

I would like the page to be able to show country details even after refreshing. I tried with if statement inside AboutCountry.vue, but it didn't work.

Comment: Most likely, you are accessing `useCountriesStore.countries` before it has loaded in App.vue. Hard to say though without looking at the store or knowing what error you get. (you might want to add that to the answer).